# Check with JS or jQuery where moved mouse after mouseleave

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm PHP, and sometimes is hard with JS :) There is menu. When hover `#about`, opens `#wrapper` .Is there a way to check with JS or jQuery where moved mouse after
`$('#company-wrapper').mouseleave` ?

```
$('#about').mouseenter(function(){
    $('.hide_wrap').stop();
    $('.hide_wrap').hide();
    $('#company-wrapper').slideDown();
});

$('#company-wrapper').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).css('display','block');
    $('#about').addClass('hov');
});

$('#about').mouseleave(function(){
    $('#company-wrapper').css('display','none');
});

$('#company-wrapper').mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).css('display','none');
    $('#about').removeClass('hov');
});
```

Problem is that I don't need to close `#company-wrapper` and `removeClass('hov')` from `#about` in case if mouse returned from `#company-wrapper` to `#about`.
And if mouse moved from `#company-wrapper` not to `#about`, then I need to close `#company-wrapper` and `removeClass('hov')`

Tryied to do it with hidden input by asigning values to it, but it helped partially - it didn't closed `#company-wrapper` when mouse returned from `#company-wrapper` to #about, but when mouse left from `#company-wrapper` not to `#about` - it didn't closed #company-wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

```
var timer = 200;
var timerId = setTimeout(func, timer );
var timerId2 = setTimeout(func2, timer );
clearTimeout(timerId);
clearTimeout(timerId2);
function func() {
 $('#company-wrapper').css('display','none');
 $('#about').removeClass('hov');
}

function func2() {
 $('#company-wrapper').css('display','none');
}
var elem_about = document.querySelector("#about");
$('#about').mouseenter(function(){
    if ($("#id_what_open_wrapper").val()=='company-wrapper') {
                if(elem_about.classList.contains("hov")){
                    console.log('about has hov');
                }else{
                    console.log('about has NOT hov');
                    $('#company-wrapper').css('display','block');
                    $('#about').addClass('hov');
                }
            clearTimeout(timerId);
            clearTimeout(timerId2);
            $("#id_what_open_wrapper").val('');
    }else{
        clearTimeout(timerId2);
        clearTimeout(timerId);
        $('.hide_wrap').stop();
        $('.hide_wrap').hide();
        $('#company-wrapper').slideDown();
    }
});

$('#company-wrapper').mouseenter(function(){
    clearTimeout(timerId2);
    clearTimeout(timerId);
    $(this).css('display','block');
    $('#about').addClass('hov');
});

$('#about').mouseleave(function(){
    timerId2 = setTimeout( func2, timer );
    timerId = setTimeout( func, timer );
});

$('#company-wrapper').mouseleave(function(){
    timerId = setTimeout( func, timer );
    timerId2 = setTimeout( func2, timer );
    $("#id_what_open_wrapper").val('company-wrapper');
});
```